# Why can't this c program run correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

Here's some code in C. Basically, It create a small binary tree and then traverse it in pre-order recursively. While I expect '1 2 3', it keeps give me 'printf' result '0 0 3'.

Does anybody have any idea about the code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct binary_tree{
  struct binary_tree *left;
  struct binary_tree *right;
  int value;
}binary_tree;

void init_btree(binary_tree *root);

// traverse the tree in pre-order recursively
void pre_order_r(const binary_tree *root){
  if(root == NULL){
    return;
  }
  printf("%d ", root->value);
  pre_order_r(root->left);
  pre_order_r(root->right);
}

int main() {
  binary_tree *root = (binary_tree*)malloc(sizeof(binary_tree*));;
  init_btree(root);
  pre_order_r(root);
  printf("\n");
}

void init_btree(binary_tree *root){
  root->left = root->right = NULL;
  root->value = 1;
  binary_tree * p1 = (binary_tree*)malloc(sizeof(binary_tree*));
  p1->left = p1->right = NULL;
  p1->value = 2;
  binary_tree * p2 = (binary_tree*)malloc(sizeof(binary_tree*));
  p2->left = p2->right = NULL;
  p2->value = 3;

  root->left = p1;
  root->right = p2;
}
```

Comment: `(binary_tree*)malloc(sizeof(binary_tree*))` --> `(binary_tree*)malloc(sizeof(binary_tree))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your problem is

```
binary_tree *root = (binary_tree*)malloc(sizeof(binary_tree*));
```

`root` is a pointer to `binary_tree` type. So, you need to allocate memory for the `binary_tree` structure, not a *"pointer-to-structure"*.

If you want a clearer picture, you can print the sizes of both `binary_tree` and `*binary_tree` using `sizeof()`.

You can re-write that allocation statement in a robust way as

```
 binary_tree *root = malloc(sizeof*root);
```

Some general advices:

1. Always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.
2. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
3. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Cast is not a problem.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes sir, but isn't it advisable?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
(binary_tree*) malloc(sizeof(binary_tree*))
```

to

```
malloc(sizeof(binary_tree))
```

You want memory for this struct, not memory for a pointer for this struct.

And don't cast the value of malloc. This is needed in C++, but you are programming in C where an implicit conversion is doing this for you.